# Set image in a ListView using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I want to set image in my ListView, my intention is to take a string contain the address of the image (ex. "@drawable/image") from database and to set the images for the element of the LisView. I have already create a custom SimpleCursorAdapter to change the font.This is my custom SimpleCursorAdapter code:

```
public class CustomFontExampleAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter 
{
    private Typeface mCustomFont;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CustomFontExampleAdapter(final Context context, final int layout, final Cursor c, final String[] from,
                final int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        mCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font/Pompiere-Regular.ttf");
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        final TextView _TextViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.record_nome);     
        _TextViewTitle.setTypeface(mCustomFont);                          
    }

}
```

This is my code when i set the adapter:

```
d= new Database(getActivity());

        final Cursor c = d.scelta();

        CursorLoader(c);

        String from[] = {Codice.DATI_ID,
                Codice.DATI_NOME_DIETA};

        int to[] = {R.id.record_id,
                R.id.record_nome};

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        CustomFontExampleAdapter sca = new CustomFontExampleAdapter(rootView.getContext(),
                R.layout.singolo_elemento,
                c, from, to);
        sceltadieta = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.scelta_dieta);
        sceltadieta.setAdapter(sca);
```

Answer (score 0):

after this line :

```
_TextViewTitle.setTypeface(mCustomFont);
```

Yous should go :

```
ImageView _ImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_image_id)

    //Suppose you've already get your string(because it's not part of a question)
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                  .getIdentifier(yourStringName, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
_ImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable)
```

Oh, and as far as i see you have no context in your adapter, putting context to adapter is common thing, you should past it throw constructor(as you did), and storing reference for it(create field and initialize it by context from constructor)

Comment: sorry nik can you explain how to get also the string?

Comment: do you have database written?

Comment: yes, I have filled it with the reference of every image

Comment: and this string would be your_filed_for_image_name from current item in cursor, that's all, do you know howto get it?